# Can't display unicode character for subscript 2 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, unicode, pyqt

I show a unicode string from an xml file in a QLabel. I need to show H<sub>2</sub>O in a QLabel but with the digit '2' as subscript (Unicode character U+2082). QLabel can take an html string but I can't put this html into the xml.

It shows correctly in Linux, but in Windows it shows some garbage instead of subscript 2. I tried many different methods (incl. changing font family), but none of them works in Windows. Why?

Comment: What code are you using to produce this result? Are you sure you've decoded the text properly before showing it in the label?

Comment: Simply with self.lb_input_unit.setText(input_unit), where input_unit is a unicode string taken directly from the xml without any decoding. The xml has all strings in unicode and they're all displayed correctly in a browser. There's something with Python on Windows. As I said, the subscript 2 shows fine on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a font issue, rather than Python. Not all fonts in Windows have U+2082. You need to pick a proper font that contains this character.

For example "Arial Unicode MS" has this. Consider the example below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtGui.QWidget()

unicode_font = QtGui.QLabel(u"Unicode Font: H\u2082O")
unicode_font.setStyleSheet("font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;") 

normal_font = QtGui.QLabel(u"Normal Font: H\u2082O")
normal_font.setStyleSheet("font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;")


layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(unicode_font)
layout.addWidget(normal_font)
widget.setLayout(layout)
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On Win 7 32-Bit it gives:

[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I have self.lb_input_unit = QLabel(u"H\u2082O") self.lb_input_unit.setStyleSheet("font-family:: Arial Unicode MS;") but it still doesn't show the 2

Comment: @user665327: If the code you just pasted is exactly the same in your script, then there is a typo. Note `::`. Other than that, check if you actually have that font. You can also check with `charmap.exe` to find a suitable font.